# Combine 2 functions (templated) in only one

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, boost-hana

I am trying to get a `boost::hana::string` by order as inserted in tuple looking by `std::string_view` name in an array (please check code, it is easier to understand there than in my words).

I have got it, but the syntax really gets messy and lost its self-explanatory meaning, because it is necessary to call two functions (1 fn for getting the index, and 1 templ. fn por getting the string) instead of only one direct call.

Please, be aware that the problem is harder than it looks, due to the fact that `boost::hana::string` returns a different type even if you change a single char in the string, regardless their lengths.

The source code is also available in coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45ea8db0d6b4dbad

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <boost/hana/string.hpp>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

constexpr std::array images = { "USERS.PNG"sv, "LESSONS.PNG"sv, "COURSES.PNG"sv, "ALUMNS.PNG"sv };
constexpr std::tuple sources = { BOOST_HANA_STRING("1"), BOOST_HANA_STRING("2"), BOOST_HANA_STRING("3"), BOOST_HANA_STRING("4") };

constexpr size_t image(const std::string_view& name)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for (auto& image : images)
        if (image == name || !++i) break;

    return i;
}

template <size_t I>
constexpr auto source()
{
    return std::get<I>(sources);
}

//constexpr auto combined(const std::string_view& name)
//{
//    constexpr auto index = image(name);
//    return source<index>();
//}

int main()
{
    //constexpr auto hana_str = combined("LESSONS.PNG"sv);
    
    constexpr auto index = image("LESSONS.PNG"sv);
    constexpr auto hana_string = source<index>();

    static_assert(std::string_view(hana_string.c_str()) == "2"sv);
}
```

The function I would like to have is the commented as "combined" in above code.

Comment: The problem is that `name` is a runtime parameter of `combined()`. As you pointed out, the return type of `source()` changes depending on the value of the template parameter `I`, but because `combined()` is just a function, it can only have one return type, regardless of the value of `name`.

Comment: Does it mean that the problem is irresolvable in compilation time using a single function? Does someone know other strategy to reach this (like boost::hana::map or sometring I may have skipped out)?

Comment: Here's a possible solution: https://godbolt.org/z/7KWT8hjsq

Comment: @Patrick Roberts: Thank you, that was clever. You are using a string that can be solved at compile time and pass it as template parameter so it generates a diferent functions anytime a new name is invoked. It is fine for me, would you like to upgrade your comment into an answer so people could vote for it?

Comment: I don't understand what "2 x 1" is supposed to mean in the question title.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think it was supposed to mean "2-in-1" based on the context.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, it was not the best title in world. I have change it to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `boost::hana::string` to `combined()` instead in order to invoke `image()` at compile-time with `std::string_view`:

```cpp
template <class CharT, CharT... s>
constexpr auto combined(const boost::hana::string<s...>& name)
{
   constexpr auto index = image(name.c_str());
   return source<index>();
}
```

And here's how to use it:

```cpp
using boost::hana::literals::operator""_s;
constexpr auto hana_str = combined("LESSONS.PNG"_s);
static_assert(hana_str.c_str() == "2"sv);
```

But [in order to enable `boost::hana::literals::operator""_s` you need to define `BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1string.html#ad77f7afff008c2ce15739ad16a8bf0a8) before including `<boost/hana/string.hpp>`:

```cpp
#define BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL
#include <boost/hana/string.hpp>
```

Comment: Also, as an off-topic comment, just to say that  ```_s ``` does not work in MS Visual Studio 2017 or below, sadly. Anyway, your solution is still valid calling it by  ```BOOST_HANA_STRING(string) ``` althought is slightly more verbose.